# How to load my html background video as a streaming video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i created a coming soon webpage using html and bootstrap.It works fine but it plays my background video after video fully downloaded.
so i want to make it like a buffering video based on a internet connectivity like youtube.That means i want it to auto pause the video when downloading and continue automatically when downloads a next part of the video.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="author" content="AKASH">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

 <title>test</title>  
<style>
.video-bg{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-bg > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* 1. No object-fit support: */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-bg > video { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-bg > video { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
/* 2. If supporting object-fit, overriding (1): */
@supports (object-fit: cover) {
  .video-bg > video {
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}


</style>
</head> 
  <body>
  <div class="video-bg" style="position:fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: -1;overflow: hidden;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="http://brosnya.com/video/Final_video.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video></div>
  </body>
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/akashmurugan/42taLvp9/10/)

i used this video tag element.Is there any alternative solution for this code to make a video streaming.

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you even looked at the documentation for  the [`<video>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)?

Comment: You've mentioned YouTube player, so do it by embedding YT with autoplay option.
Just because you need to stream your video it seems that this file might be too heavy - try to optimize with decresing movie resolution and creating "poster" with framework like video.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `video` element itself but with the video **file**.

In principle, video files like *mp4*, *avi* and *mkv* have the **index** file at the end. That means that you have to download the **entire** file before being able to play it *correctly*. So, what you need to do is re-encode the file and place the index at the beginning.

The only option that the `video` element offers, is quite the opposite. Meaning that you can turn autoplay off and/or turn preload on so that the video (that has the index file at the beginning) will only start playing when its fully loaded.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp